# Oracle 11g temporary lob not freeable

Tags: oracle11g, temporary, oracle11gr2, lob

I´m using Oracle 11gR2, can someone tell me why the temporary lob isn´t freed?

```
    ... 
    -- Apply stylesheet to DOM document
    outdomdocf := dbms_xslprocessor.processxsl(proc, xsl, indomdoc);
    outnode := dbms_xmldom.makenode(outdomdocf);

    -- Write the transformed output to the CLOB
    dbms_lob.createTemporary(outfile, true, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
    dbms_xmldom.writetoCLOB(outnode, outfile);

    -- Free Cursors
    outXML := XMLTYPE.createXml(outfile);
    dbms_lob.freeTemporary(outfile);            <-- not working
    ...
```

When I do

```
select * from v$temporary_lobs;
```

It´s still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `DBMS_LOB.CLOSE()` to close it before calling `DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY()` .